# Reset vertex attributes with disabled array between two runs of the same shader?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I would like to plot a bunch of curves from multi-dimensional data. For each curve I have a dataset of `M` variables, where each variable is either a vector of length `N` or just a scalar value:

```
x1 = [x11,x12,.......,x1N] OR x1 = X1 (scalar value)
x2 = [x21,x22,.......,x2N] OR x2 = X2
....
xM = [xM1,xM2,.......,xMN] OR xM = XM
```

My curve shader takes three float attributes `x,y,z` which represent the variables that are currently on display.
For each curve and each `x,y,z`, I bind a vertex buffer containing the data for the respective variable to the attribute if the data is a vector. Drawing multiple curves with only vector data works fine.

If the data for some variable is just a scalar number, I disable the attribute array and set the attribute value (for example X1) with:

```
glDisableVertexAttribArray(xLocation);  
glVertexAttrib1f(xLocation,X1);
```

Now to my question: It seems that all curves use the *same* value for any vertex attribute  with disabled array in the shader, (the one for the last curve that I draw) even though i reset the values between `glDrawArray()` calls. Is it just not possible to use more than one value for an attribute with disabled array in a shader, or should it be possible and I have a bug?

Comment: I'm not really sure if I understand the question correctly. You can set a value for every attribute for which the array is disabled. You should just be aware that when you draw with some attribute _enabled_ and then disable it, the value of that attribute is _undefined_ and you have to re-specify it using the `glVertexAttrib*()` functions.

Comment: say I want to plot two copies of the parabola y=x**2, in 3D, one of them at z=0 and the other at z=1. For that, I would *enable* x and y, but *disable* z and set it to 0 for the first run and to 1 for the second run - this twofold setting of z does not work, though

Comment: That _should_ actually work.

Comment: Ok, then I guess it's back to the code. Thanks!

Comment: What you're describing in the latest version of the question sounds perfectly fine. You can call `glVertexAttrib1f()` before each draw call, and then that value will be used for that draw call. I suspect that there's either something in your code that is not mentioned here, or you're encountering a driver bug.

Comment: Couple of suggestions to diagnose this: Do you have another machine you can test it on, ideally with a GPU from a different vendor, or running on a different platform? Also, just as an experiment, can you add a `glFinish()` call after each draw call, and see if it changes anything?

Comment: Ok, now I discovered that I even run into problems with a single curve sometimes - the mistake is definitely somewhere in my code, sorry for bothering you and thanks for your suggestions!